# tikz overlay relative to equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, overlays

What would be the easiest way of overlaying tikz output on environments other than a page?

At the top of the code below is an example that puts some tikz output at a specific place on the page.  How would one do that for other constructs like an equation?  (bottom of code)

The example is for an equation and an image, but the question is intended to be general.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]  % works
\node[anchor=south west] (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{pig}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage

\begin{equation}  
 z=x+y
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current equation.south west)}]
 \node[anchor=south west] (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\equationwidth,height=\equationheight]{pig}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Needless to say, there is no predefined (current equation) node. You could create one by putting the equation {$\displaystyle ...$} inside a node.  Usually one uses \tikzmark instead.

Comment: Thanks.  But the `$\displaystyle$` option precludes lots of useful features of equations such as equation numbers, multiple lines, etcetera, and how would I get `\tikzmark` to put something in an absolute location inside the equation box instead of relative to content?

Comment: Place one tikzmark on the top left and one on the bottom right and interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needless to say, I had to use an image other than "pig".  The first puts the equation inside the tikzpicture, while the second put the tikzpicture inside the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\equationwidth}
\newlength{\equationheight}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \node[inner sep=0pt] (current equation)
     {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{equation} z=x+y\end{equation}\end{minipage}};
   \pgfextractx{\equationwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{west}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{east}}}%
   \pgfextracty{\equationheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{south}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{north}}}%
   \node[opacity=0.6,inner sep=0pt] at (current equation)
     {\includegraphics[width=\equationwidth,height=\equationheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{equation}  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \node[anchor=base] (current equation) {$\displaystyle z=x+y$};
   \pgfextractx{\equationwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{west}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{east}}}%
   \pgfextracty{\equationheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{south}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{north}}}%
   \node[opacity=0.6] at (current equation)
     {\includegraphics[width=\equationwidth,height=\equationheight]{example-image}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% check alignment

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

The following is the same except it puts the equation on top of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newlength{\equationwidth}
\newlength{\equationheight}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt] (current equation)
     {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{equation} z=x+y\end{equation}\end{minipage}};
   \pgfextractx{\equationwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{west}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{east}}}%
   \pgfextracty{\equationheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{south}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{north}}}%
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current equation)
       {\includegraphics[width=\equationwidth,height=\equationheight]{example-image}};
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{equation}  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \node[anchor=base] (current equation) {$\displaystyle z=x+y$};
   \pgfextractx{\equationwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{west}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{east}}}%
   \pgfextracty{\equationheight}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{south}}%
     {\pgfpointanchor{current equation}{north}}}%
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current equation)
       {\includegraphics[width=\equationwidth,height=\equationheight]{example-image}};
   \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}% check alignment

\end{document}
```